# What is the Linux 3.8.0-XX all about?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, updates, hardware

So to keep it simple, my hardware wasn't working on 13.04 so I advanced booted with Linux 3.8.0-19 rather than 3.8.0-31 and like magic it all worked. So why is this? Can I always boot with this Linux version/kernel/whatever? Can I update ubuntu like normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last number from the Linux kernel name is changed *when any bug is patched or any error is corrected in the kernel*. So, this means: the more this number is higher, the kernel should be better.

Once you have installed/updated a new version of the kernel, at next reboot your system will use the new installed kernel. And yes, you can  update Ubuntu like normal after this.

Comment: Hmm... So my hardware doesn't work on the newest version. Is that normal?

Comment: @user199952 Nope, is not normal, but yes, this can happen. It's not uncommon. Depends on your hardware.

Comment: So is there a way to force ubuntu to boot with this kernel?

Comment: @user199952 Yes, at boot time, from the GRUB boot menu, select **Advanced options** (or something like this).

Comment: Will this temporarily change the option or will this be permanent?

Comment: @user199952 Well, try it and you will see.